# Logic error when add tag for post in Laravel

Tags: laravel, tagging

I trying function add tag for post in laravel. This is update code:

```
public function update(PostRequest $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    $post->update($request->all());

    if ($request->tags) {
        $tagNames = explode(',', $request->tags);
        $tagIds = [];

        foreach ($tagNames as $tagName) {
            $tagCount = Tag::where('name', '=', $tagName)->count();
            if ($tagCount < 1) {
                $tag = $post->tags()->create(['name' => $tagName]);
            } else {
                $post->tags()->detach();
                $tag = Tag::where('name', $tagName)->first();
            }
            $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
        }
        $post->tags()->sync($tagIds);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Successfully');
}
```

It works well with pivot table, this has been resolved.

My problem lies in the tag table. When I delete all tags and retype new tag or exist tag, ok it works.

But when I do not change or keeping old tag and continue add new tag will cause an logic error. It will automatically add the record to the tags table.
For example: my post has 3 tags: test1, test2, test3. I keep it and add a tag: test4 then in the table tag automatically add tag: test2, test3, test4.

Is there a solution to my problem? Where was I wrong? I spent almost 2 days for it. I don't want to use package. Vote up for answer useful.

Comment: Is it many-to-many? Why do you detach a tag? It will `sync` anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is many to many. What should I do?

Comment: I'm curious if I understood the bug correctly. Describe, please, what's wrong with your code? Is it a wrong entry at tags table or wrong relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `firstOrCreate`, it is short and convenient. Then, don't detach, it is useless, `sync` makes connected tags just like the array `tagIds`, it removes non-existing elements out of a pivot table and adds new ones.

In addition, you have spaces between commas and words, so you need to `trim` it.

```
if ($request->tags) {
    $tagNames = explode(',', $request->tags);
    $tagIds = [];

    foreach ($tagNames as $tagName) {
        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['name' => trim($tagName)]);
        $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
    }
    $post->tags()->sync($tagIds);
}
```

I think I've understood your bug, it is here

```
if ($tagCount < 1) {
    $tag = $post->tags()->create(['name' => $tagName]);
} else {
    $post->tags()->detach();
    $tag = Tag::where('name', $tagName)->first();
}
```

It means that when you pass a new tag, it removes all the related tags out of the post. If you pass only old tags, they are not removed.

Comment: It does not matter what the pivot post_tag table has but the problem with the tag table.